# how to reset value of steps in google maps v3 animation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

this is my example http://gidzior.net/map/v3_animate_marker_directions.html (i'm using placeholder in the input), core of GM code is from geocodezip.com, i develop the code with the great help of Andrew Leach

1500 meters in the animation before the destination is set to zoom could be seen to better reach this destination point, unfortunately, after zoom, animation is not smooth and therefore I set the "step" value to 15, how to reset this value after animation stops

i set step = 15 - `if (d>eol-1500 && zoomed!=true) { map.setZoom(15); step = 15; zoomed=true; }`

WHOLE SCRIPT

```
      var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.0000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var zoomed;
  var zoomedd;
  var zoomeddd;

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

  var size = new google.maps.Size(26,25);
  var start_point = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
  var foothold = new google.maps.Point(13,15);

  var car_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://gidzior.net/map/car.png", size, start_point, foothold);

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: car_icon,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
    return marker;
}


function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Create a map and center it on Warszawa.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'warszawa'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }



    var steps = []

    function calcRoute(){

if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
polyline.setMap(null);
poly2.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      suppressMarkers:true
    }
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: travelMode,
            waypoints: [{
                location:new google.maps.LatLng(52.185570, 20.997255),
                stopover:false}],
            optimizeWaypoints: false
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        // For each route, display summary information.
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
            marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



            }
          }
        }

        polyline.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = (polyline.Distance()/1000).toFixed(2)+" km";
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
//        createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
    map.setZoom(18);
    startAnimation();
    zoomed=false;
    zoomedd=false;
    zoomeddd=false;
    }                                                    
 });
}



      var step = 50; // 5; // metres
      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "";
      var lastVertex = 1;


//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {;
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        if (d>eol-20000 && zoomeddd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(12); // or whatever value
          zoomeddd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-10000 && zoomedd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(13); // or whatever value
          zoomedd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-1500 && zoomed!=true) {
          map.setZoom(15); // or whatever value
          step = 15;
          zoomed=true;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get to this, thanks anyway

i took var step = 50; to the the top

```
var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.0000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var zoomed;
  var zoomedd;
  var zoomeddd;

  var step = 50; // 5; // metres

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;
```

i set step = 50; to the end of calcRoute() function and now animation works fine