# Animate a route with google map js api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

Given two geo-localized points (start and end of the route), I want to animate the drawing of the route between them.

Do you know how if it's achievable with the Google map js v3 api?

Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible to animate a marker along the route: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html. Version 2 example of animated route line: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm

Comment: ...and if you prefer to fly instead of driving: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_flight_path_animated.html

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277005/how-to-reset-value-of-steps-in-google-maps-v3-animation) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904476/js-google-maps-api-v3-animate-marker-between-coordinates) try: marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

Answer (score 14):

I found something for you.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html
Visit this website hit F12 on chrome go to sources tab and select v3-animate-marker-direction.html 
You'll the complete code of it on how it is used. I you need help on it, kindly comment

and a pretty good example here also, but I guess it is implemented on v2
http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/

Regards, 
Suyash

Comment: Thanks, Can I have one solution the same with only increasing route color.

Answer (score 6):

Using this [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleMarkerAnimation.html) you can animate more than one markers within the route. the animate and startAnimation functions handle multiple markers. You can modify the code based on your requirement. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

In this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom):

```
var symbolTwo = {
  path: 'M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 -3,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0M 1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,0 1,1 0 0 0 1,0M -3,3 Q 0,5 3,3',
  strokeColor: '#00F',
  **rotation**: 45
};
```